# Input current datetime in local time by default in django model

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, pytz

I have created a model in Django in which I want to input creation time by default in local time. I have set the following in settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_TZ = True
```

I have tried the following:

```
import pytz

status_timezone = pytz.timezone('Etc/UTC')

class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=status_timezone.localize(datetime.now()))
```

This always gives the same datetime for all entries (time of model initialization

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

This gives datetime in UTC

How to input datetime in IST by default?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change.

```
USE_TZ = False
```

By so doing you will stop using `UTC` 
and `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'` will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#datefield) the auto_now_add is populated with the default time zone. As described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) this is populated according to `TIME_ZONE` settings.

Hence - I think the answer to your question would be:

`TIME_ZONE=Asia/Kolkota`

`creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)`

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern for it is the following:

`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this would be like

in 'settings/py':

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata' #'UTC' 

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

in 'models.py':

```
from django.utils import timezone
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now, blank=False)
```

Comment: USE_TZ=FALSE for local datetime